# Using authselect command to configure nsswitch.conf for LDAP in Almalinux 8

Tags: ldap, ldapconnection, sssd

I need to adjust my passwd, group, netgroup, and automount in the nsswitch.conf file to be LDAP compatible.  It does not allow me to manually adjust these settings and requires me to use the authselect command to adjust things.

This is the current section of nsswitch.conf I'm trying to change:

```
# Generated by authselect on Tue Feb 20 16:46:31 2024
# Do not modify this file manually.

# If you want to make changes to nsswitch.conf please modify
# /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf and run 'authselect apply-changes'.
#
# Note that your changes may not be applied as they may be
# overwritten by selected profile. Maps set in the authselect
# profile takes always precedence and overwrites the same maps
# set in the user file. Only maps that are not set by the profile
# are applied from the user file.
#
# For example, if the profile sets:
#     passwd: sss files
# and /etc/authselect/user-nsswitch.conf contains:
#     passwd: files
#     hosts: files dns
# the resulting generated nsswitch.conf will be:
#     passwd: sss files # from profile
#     hosts: files dns  # from user file

passwd:     files sss systemd
group:      files sss systemd
netgroup:   sss files
automount:  sss files
services:   sss files`
```

I have tried:

```
authselect select sssd
```

and a few of the modifiers within the command to no avail.  None of what I have tried has put ldap in the passwd, group, netgroup, or automount configurations.

Does anyone have any information on how to use authselect properly change the nsswitch.conf file?

Comment: Isn't the current file you posted already LDAP-compatible? It has `sss` in practically every category.

Comment: I specifically need to set this file up to have it look like:

    passwd:     files sss systemd LDAP
    group:      files sss systemd LDAP
    netgroup:   sss files LDAP
    automount:  sss files LDAP
    services:   sss files

It doesn't currently seem to be able to authenticate the LDAP services with autofs.  I could be completely wrong about what the issue is but checking this file against the same file on other systems in our building leads me to believe the difference here is my issue.

Comment: Are your other systems using `nslcd` or PADL nss_ldap? There is more than one LDAP client for nsswitch – you need to decide whether you want to use SSSD or nslcd first.

Comment: To be honest I am unsure.  nslcd is on the machime I'm working with and can see our ldap server.  When it is active, autofs status via systemctl appears to see ldap.  I just get a password authentication failure when I attempt to login with ldap credentials.  Is there a place where I can check to see what the server is expecting me to use?

Comment: It has little to do with the server; both SSSD and nslcd are clients for the same LDAP protocol and can talk to any LDAP server (though SSSD has some advantages when it comes to AD or IPA). You currently have SSSD (the `sss` module) active because it's the default on RedHat distros, so I would first try to configure SSSD, and only if that doesn't work out, install nslcd (aka nss-pam-ldapd, the `ldap` module).